# Two Browse Buttons -Upload

Tags: php

I have a form with 2 Browse buttons,how i can able to tackle it,Multiple file upload is different,Previously i have working example with single Browse button,but how i can used the same code for second browse,i copied the first button code and change the name attribute for second,but this is not the good way to do.

doc1 is name attribute for browse button1
doc2 is name attribute for browse button2

```
if($_POST['submit'])
{
if(isset($_FILES['doc1'])){
    $errors= array();
    $file_name = $_FILES['doc1']['name'];
    $file_size =$_FILES['doc1']['size'];
    $file_tmp =$_FILES['doc1']['tmp_name'];
    $file_type=$_FILES['doc1']['type'];

    $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['doc1']['name'])));
    $extensions = array("pdf","docx","doc");

    if(in_array($file_ext,$extensions )=== false){
     echo "Extension not allowed, please choose a pdf,docx or doc format.";
    }
    if($file_size > 5500000){
    echo'File size must be exactly 2 MB';
    }               
    if(empty($errors)==true){
        $path = 'uploads/'.$file_name;

        //mkdir($path, 0777, true);
        //$dirn=mkdir('uploads/'.$file_name,0777,true);


        move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$path);

        echo "Success";
    }else{
        print_r($errors);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: "See the code,pls alter it." **No.** StackOverflow is _not_ here to do your work for you. You need to clarify your problem, and you need to ask for advice, not for someone to "alter [your code]"

Comment: oopz,Sorry,take my words back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if($_POST['submit'])
{
for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES['doc1']);$i++)
{

if(isset($_FILES['doc1'][$i])){
$errors= array();
$file_name = $_FILES['doc1'][$i]['name'];
$file_size =$_FILES['doc1'][$i]['size'];
$file_tmp =$_FILES['doc1'][$i]['tmp_name'];
$file_type=$_FILES['doc1'][$i]['type'];

$file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['doc1'][$i]['name'])));
$extensions = array("pdf","docx","doc");

if(in_array($file_ext,$extensions )=== false){
 echo "Extension not allowed, please choose a pdf,docx or doc format.";
}
if($file_size > 5500000){
echo'File size must be exactly 2 MB';
}               
if(empty($errors)==true){
    $path = 'uploads/'.$file_name;

    //mkdir($path, 0777, true);
    //$dirn=mkdir('uploads/'.$file_name,0777,true);


    move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$path);

    echo "Success";
}else{
    print_r($errors);
}
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you do not want to use two different names for your browser button, make an array of it like,

```
<input type="file" name="doc1[]">
<input type="file" name="doc1[]">
```

So you just have to access this array for the future operations.

Comment: can you pls explain more